# Picasso loads images slowly to recycler view on network

Tags: android, picasso

I am loading images to a recyclerview and it is taking about 30 seconds to load an image from the network. Here is the code:

```
public void bindEvent(Event event){
            datetime.setText(event.getTime());
            description.setText(event.getDescription());
            event_name.setText(event.getName());


            Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context).loggingEnabled(true);


            builder.build().load(event.getEventPicUrl()).fit().into(event_picture);



        }
```

Here is the code for the imageview:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/event_picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    />
```

Comment: What is size of your image?

Comment: @MohammedAtif The size ranges between 500 and 700 KB

Comment: I don't really think that this is the reason for your performance problem - but one thing to note: It seems like you are creating a new `Picasso` instance for each `Event`. As this also creates new instances of all the internal supporting classes (`OkHttpDownloader`, `LruCache`, etc.) this very probably not what you want. In general you should use `Picasso.with`. And if you need a custom instance you should "deploy" it by calling `setSingletonInstance` before your first call to `with`.

Comment: @david.mihola I have changed to Picasso.with but the speed has not improved.

Comment: @zacmwa It might help if you could post an excerpt of the Picasso log...  Have you tried just loading some other images from the web, just to see if it's a server issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Glide Library to load images.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

more information about [Glide](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/).